Something's not right with the value in parameter body
I created a flow with an http call out action aiming at updating a custom field on a Jira issue.
When trying to connect for schema, I'm currently getting the following error:
[Error Message]: Something's not right with the value in parameter "body" for the selected media type application/json. Check it and try again.

What's surprising is that I'm also getting a response code 204, meaning that the update in Jira was successful and when looking at the issue in Jira, the custom field was well updated.
But, because of this error, I'm not able to save changes to my call-out action and I can't activate my flow.
Do you know how I can work around this error?
Thank you.

Had the same issue, the response body was empty, thus incorrectly formatted.
The solution was to return a dummy value.
Hope it helps!

Thanks a lot for your help. But what do you mean by "return a dummy value". How did you actuallly achieve that?

You're surely right, because on this page about the Jira REST API https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-example-edit-issues-6291632/ we can read "Response: You should just receive a response with a status of "204 No Content"". So that's it! Response body is empty. But how do you actually manage to  "return a dummy value"?

I have the same issue with you. Can you share more details about the solution for this error? Thank you so much.
